# How to share .txt file using MultipeerConnectivity Framework between two IOS devices

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

txt file from one ios device another ios device through ios app.

Is any example available,please suggest me some one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `MCSession`'s `sendResourceAtURL...` method once both devices have joined the same session:

```
session.sendResourceAtURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file.txt"), withName: "file.txt", toPeer: peer, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

There's several tutorials available for setting up a connection between two devices using the MultipeerConnectivity framework, such as [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exploring-the-multipeer-connectivity-framework-project-setup--mobile-23071).